# flat list from nested elements in marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Is it possible in Marionette to generate a flat list out of a nested list of models and collections?

For instance i would like to generate a select element with each node as an option (child options should be indented):

```
[
  {
    nodeName: "top level 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 1",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 1" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 2" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 2",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 4" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 5"},
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 6" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This should become something like:

```
<select>
    <option>top level 1</option>
    <option>   2nd level, item 1</option>
    <option>      3nd level, item 1</option>
    <option>      3nd level, item 2</option>
    <option>      3nd level, item 3</option>
    <option>   2nd level, item 2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

So far I have been trying with nested composite views (as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hoffmanc/NH9J6/), but I haven't been able to make it work properly.

Regards

Comment: here is a running version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/NH9J6/219/, removed the raw github dependencies replacing some with cdn version and others were not being used so i just removed them. Also changed itemView to chiewView on you treeRoot as that what it has been changed to in marionette 2.*. so is it that you want the indentation to display when this renders?

Comment: ok thanks! I see! The fiddle is not mine, but I just included it as a general approach on how to go from nested models/collections to a nested ul-list. I just want to go from nested models/collections to a flat option list. Then indentation was just to visualize the "nested structure" to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, first recursively iterate over nested and create plain JSON with node text and nest level it has for padding:

```
var flat = [];

function parseJson(nodes){
    parseJson.level = parseJson.level || 0;        

    nodes.forEach(function(node, i){
        flat.push({ text:node.name, level: parseJson.level});
        if(node.nodes){
            parseJson.level++;
            parseJson(node.nodes);
        } 
        (i == nodes.length -1) && parseJson.level--;
    })
}

/* or you can get flat array with reduce */

var rawJson = [/* Your json here */], 
    flat = rawJson.reduce(function rec(memo, item, i, array){
        rec.level = rec.level || 0;
        memo.push({ text: item.n, level: rec.level });
        if(item.nodes){
            rec.level++;  
            item.nodes.reduce(rec, memo);
        }

        (i == array.length -1) && rec.level--;

        return memo;
}, []);
```

`nodes` is your raw json. In `flat` you will have elements like this:

```
{
    text: 'node text',
    level: 2
}
```

Next, create Model and Collection for view rendering:

```
var NodeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'unnamed',
            level: 0
        }
    }),
    NodeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: NodeModel 
    });
```

Then Views:

```
var NodeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'option',
        template: '#node-template'
    }),
    NodeCollectionView =  Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        itemView: NodeView /* or childView if Marionette v 2.0.*/
    });
```

Then template:

```
<% _.times(level, function(){ %> &nbsp; <% }); %> <%= text %>
```

And finally:

```
(new NodeCollectionView({
  collection: new NodeCollection(flat),
  el: 'body'
})).render();
```

thats all) Hope this help;

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using underscore.js's _.flatten() method? It could be much simpler. 
[flattening nested arrays/objects in underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628912/flattening-nested-arrays-objects-in-underscore-js)