# angular - flatten array of objects of the same type

Tags: javascript, angular, flatten

what's the cleanest way to flatten an array of objects that have this type interface:

```
Interface {
 Item: Item,
 SubItems: Array<Item>
}
```

example of an array:

```
    myArray = [
{Item: {id: "bla1"}, SubItems: [{id: "bla2"}, {id: "bla3"}, {id: "bla4"}]}, 
{Item: {id: "bla5"}, SubItems: [{id: "bla6"}, {id: "bla7"}, {id: "bla8"}]}
]
```

the end result should be a single array of all these same type objects, and ordered like this:

```
first object -> Item -> SubItems
second object -> Item -> SubItems
```

so in my example I should have this:

```
flattenedArray = [{id: "bla1"}, {id: "bla2"}, {id: "bla3"}, {id: "bla4"}, ...]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flatten javascript array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243349/flatten-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: read that thread, but the answer I was given here seems much more cleaner and elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myArray.map(val => [val.Item, ...val.SubItems]).reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur])
```

Comment: works perfectly, would you mind explaning me quickly the reduce part? I read what it does but honestly didn't quite get it! thank you anyway for the answer

Comment: `reduce` iterates over your array, and executes a special function that takes an accumulator and returns a new accumulator, that is passed to the next function execution. All you have to do is to copy the previous values with `...acc` and add the new ones with `...cur`